# how to draw a group histogram graph with many levels(factors) in R?

Tags: r

I would like to plot  have the data frame as:

```
    ï..ActivityType                 15_24years      25_34years    35_44years   45+years
    sleep and personal activity          11              10            10          12
    sleeping                              8               7             7           6
    personal care                         0.5             1             1           3
    eating                                2.5             2             2           3
    paid working                          3               8             8           5
    schooling                             6               2             1           1
    others                                4               4             5           6
```

The code I used is

```
df1 <- timenew %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = ends_with("years"),
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  ) 

a <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(timenew$ï..ActivityType), y=values, fill=names)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=values), vjust=1.6, color="black",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")

b <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(timenew$ï..ActivityType), y=values, color=names, group=names)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")

plot_grid(a, b, labels = "AUTO")
```

when I use the factor and run the codes,I have the error message : `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (66): x`

The dput result shows below:

```
structure(list(ï..ActivityType = c("Sleep and personal activities", 
"Paid work activities ", "Studying or learning ", "Transport to and N/Arom activity ", 
"Unpaid work activities", "Socializing", "Civic, religious and organizational activities ", 
"Active sports and events ", "Active leisure", "Passive leisure", 
"Other or unknown activity"), Y15to24years = c("11.7", "2", "1.8", 
"1.1", "1.4", "0.9", "N/A", "0.8", "2.1", "1.8", "0.4"), Y25to34years = c("10.1", 
"4.4", "N/A", "1.4", "3", "1.1", "0.1", "0.4", "1.2", "1.8", 
"0.3"), Y35to44years = c("10.2", "4.6", "N/A", "1.2", "3.5", 
"0.9", "0.1", "0.3", "0.7", "1.9", "0.4"), Y45to54years = c("10.8", 
"3.6", "N/A", "1.1", "3.4", "0.8", "0.2", "0.4", "0.8", "2.6", 
"0.3"), Y55to64years = c("10.5", "2.8", "N/A", "1.2", "3.7", 
"1", "0.1", "0.3", "1", "3", "0.3"), Over65years = c("11.4", 
"0.6", "N/A", "0.9", "3.6", "1", "0.3", "0.3", "1.2", "4.3", 
"0.5")), row.names = c(1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 
23L, 26L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can backquote the variable in `aes`

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(`ï..ActivityType`), y=values, fill=names)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
   geom_text(aes(label=values), vjust=1.6, color="black",
             position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
   theme(legend.position = "none",
           axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70,  hjust=1))+
   xlab("ActivityType")

b <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(`ï..ActivityType`), y=values, color=names, group=names)) +
   geom_point() + 
   geom_line() +
   scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
   theme(legend.position = "none",
           axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70,  hjust=1)) + 
   xlab("ActivityType")
 plot_grid(a, b, labels = "AUTO")
```

-output

[image]

---

Or another option is `.data` to extract (`$` or `[[`)

```
a <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(.data$ï..ActivityType), y=values, fill=names)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=values), vjust=1.6, color="black",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

---

It may also better to use `facet_wrap` for the first graph

```
a <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(`ï..ActivityType`), y=values, fill=names)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
    geom_text(aes(label=values), vjust=1.6, color="black",
              position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
    theme(legend.position = "none",
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70,  hjust=1))+
    xlab("ActivityType") + 
    facet_wrap(~ names, scales = "free_y")
```